# How to import official mongodb driver package

Tags: mongodb, go

How to import official mongoDB driver package in Go?

I am following the official Go-mongoDB-driver package instruction (https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-go-driver-tutorial). I have installed the mongoDB package using this:

```
go get github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver
```

but I just can't import the package

I am doing a very simple snippet in my `main.go`

```
package main

import "github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/mongo

func main() {
}
```

This gives me:

```
main.go:8:8: code in directory $GOPATH/src/github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver/bson expects import "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
```

When I tried to import `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson`, It gives me this:

```
main.go:10:8: cannot find package "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson (from $GOROOT)
    $GOPATH/src/go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson (from $GOPATH)
```

Kindly help, quite new in Go and not sure where to look since I don't find people having this issue a lot.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The error actually gives you the answer: You must use that driver as `go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson` instead. The package has apparently changed URLs some time in the past, and the tutorial you're referring to has not yet been updated.

You should instead refer to the installation instructions [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver#installation).  In short, do this:

```
go get go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo
```

then import it using the same path:

```golang
import (
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo"
    "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson"
    // etc
)
```

Comment: But using dep isn't strictly necessary. If you keep reading, you see that it gives you the proper import paths to use, too.

Comment: I wouldn't spend time learning the ins and outs of dep given that it's not the official package manager for Go.